# Is Magic Circle created immediately next to the caster?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The description of the spell *Magic Circle* says it has a range of 10 feet, and that the radius of the circle is 10 feet.  I'm pretty sure that that means that the caster ends up standing right at the edge of the circle.  Is that the right interpretation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No**

The caster *can* be in the edge if they like or they can be inside. The center of the cylinder is anywhere you like from 0 to 10 feet from you.

The most common use is to keep the creatures *out* so you want to be on the inside where it’s safe.

The *alternative* use is to keep the creatures *in*, if so starting at the edge and using your movement to step out makes sense.